# gomobile bind gomobile: ANDROID_NDK_HOME specifies ...\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.2.9519653, which is unusable: unsupported API version 16 (not in 19..33)

Tags: android, sdk, gomobile-android

I am a learner of golang ,trying to use golang to develop android
When I want to package into APK, I encounter the following problems

I'm following the official guide to install gomobile.
OS:Win10
go version go1.20.2 windows/amd64

I have installed Android Studio and SDK Tools(NDK)

I have set patch

ANDROID_HOME  //  C:\Users\AI007\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

ANDROID_NDK_HOME  //  C:\Users\AI007\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.2.9519653

When I want to package into APK, I encounter the following problems

input command

`C:\Users\AI007>gomobile bind -target=android goapp`

show

`gomobile: ANDROID_NDK_HOME specifies C:\Users\AI007\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\25.2.9519653, which is unusable: unsupported API version 16 (not in 19..33)`

Google has found a lot of methods, how to solve this problem, it has troubled me for several days, thank you

Answer (score 0):

ok I now its a little late but I found the solution for this and that was downloading the `Unsupported NDK` from the link down below and copy the package to the `\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk` directory along side with other versions of NDK. I also updated the `ANDROID_NDK_HOME` with the new directory.

https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Unsupported-Downloads

the version that worked for me was `android-ndk-r20b-windows-x86_64.zip`.

also as the blog says :
Note: these obsolete versions of the NDK are no longer supported. Use a current release instead.

Answer (score 0):

you should add androidapi {latest android api version}" to your gomobile command.

You command will currently be:

```
gomobile bind -target=android -androidapi 21 goapp
```